# how to map Object property names into an array

Tags: php, php-5.5

I have an Object structure like this:

```
$o = new stdClass();
$o->f1 = new stdClass();
$o->f2 = 2;

$o->f1->f12 = 5;
$o->f1->f13 = "hello world";
```

And I would like to get an array of all the "leave properties' name":

```
$a = ["f2","f1f12", "f1f13"]
```

is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything??

Comment: Is there any specific technical reason why you need this? there may be better options available, or better designs to achieve your actual business goal

Answer (score 0):

```
function getObjectVarNames($object, $name = '')
{
    $objectVars = get_object_vars($object);
    $objectVarNames = array();
    foreach ($objectVars as $key => $objectVar) {
        if (is_object($objectVar)) {
            $objectVarNames = array_merge($objectVarNames, getObjectVarNames($objectVar, $name . $key));
            continue;
        }
        $objectVarNames[] = $name . $key;
    }

    return $objectVarNames;
}

$o = new stdClass();
$o->f1 = new stdClass();
$o->f2 = 2;
$o->f1->f12 = 5;
$o->f1->f13 = "hello world";

var_export(getObjectVarNames($o));
```

Result:

```
array (
  0 => 'f1f12',
  1 => 'f1f13',
  2 => 'f2',
)
```